# Two hyperlinks appear when using cmsdate=both

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, biblatex-chicago

I am using author-date citations in biblatex-chicago with `cmsdate=both` to show the original year of publication.

My document looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\usepackage[citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \autocite{Locke}
\end{document}
```

using the bib file:

```
@book{Locke,
    author  = "John Locke",
    date        = 1980,
    origdate    = 1690,
    title   = "Second Treatise of Government",
    publisher   = "Hackett",
    address = "Indianapolis, IN",
    }
```

gives me `(Locke [1690] 1980)`, where the years are hyperlinked to the references page.

There seems to be two overlapping hyperlink borders on my citation, however. One around the entirety of `[1690] 1980` and a second one around `1690` only.

This is not a huge problem, since both hyperlinks lead to the same citation, but the overlapping borders do look strange on a pdf document.

Is there a way to keep only hyperlink around `[1690] 1980` only? (Or if not, around `1690` and `1980` separately?)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

you could disable the internal link:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\usepackage[citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter 
\AtBeginDocument{%
\def\Hy@colorlink#1{\begingroup
 \long\def\blx@bibhyperref[##1]##2{##2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\autocite{Locke}
    
\end{document}
```